# Python: correct format on input to datagridview

Tags: python, datagridview

I want to add rows to a datagridview "manually". I tried converting the following code to python: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-manipulate-rows-in-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control

However, I struggle with adding rows. The following doesn't work:

```
    for j in range(len(signals)):
        self._dataGridView1.Rows.Add(signals[j])
```

The following code does work, but is not dynamically enough as I don't know how many elements there will be:

```
    for j in range(len(signals)):
        self._dataGridView1.Rows.Add(signals[j][0], signals[j][1], signals[j][2], signals[j][3])
```

How should I fix this? I tried tuple, but the result were a tuple with all the info shown in the first cell instead of spread over the columns.

I would not like to add packages, as this is to be run within revid dynamo among several users, and I cannot convince everyone to install packages.

full code for context:

```
import clr
clr.AddReference('System.Windows.Forms')
clr.AddReference('System.Drawing')
clr.AddReference('System.Data')
clr.AddReference('RevitAPIUI')


from Autodesk.Revit.UI import TaskDialog

from System.Windows.Forms import *

from System.Drawing import (
    Point, Size,
    Font, FontStyle,
    GraphicsUnit
)

from System.Data import DataSet
from System.Data.Odbc import OdbcConnection, OdbcDataAdapter

msgBox = TaskDialog

headers = IN[0]
signals = IN[1]




class DataGridViewQueryForm(Form):

        def __init__(self):
            self.Text = 'Signals'
            self.ClientSize = Size(942, 255)
            self.MinimumSize = Size(500, 200)

            self.setupDataGridView()


        def setupDataGridView(self):            
            self._dataGridView1 = DataGridView()
            self._dataGridView1.AllowUserToOrderColumns = True
            self._dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize
            self._dataGridView1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
            self._dataGridView1.Location = Point(0, 111)
            self._dataGridView1.Size = Size(506, 273)
            self._dataGridView1.TabIndex = 3
            self._dataGridView1.ColumnCount = len(headers)
            self._dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersVisible = True
            for i in range(len(headers)):
                self._dataGridView1.Columns[i].Name = headers[i]

            for j in range(len(signals)):
                self._dataGridView1.Rows.Add(signals[j][0], signals[j][1], signals[j][2], signals[j][3])

            self.Controls.Add(self._dataGridView1)





Application.Run(DataGridViewQueryForm())
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Had to use System.Array.

```
from System import Array
```

code changes:

array_str = Array.CreateInstance(str, len(headers))

```
    for j in range(len(signals)):

        for k in range(len(headers)):
            array_str[k] = signals[j][k]
        self._dataGridView1.Rows.Add(array_str)
```